# Rails MySQL migration, changing text column to decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an items database with a text column where a user would enter a number and it was saved as a string.
I need to change the column to a decimal, I have it working in postgresql from follwing another answer but don't know how to do the same in MySQL.

This is the error I get when running the migration on a MySQL database;

> Mysql2::Error: Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1:
>   ALTER TABLE `items` CHANGE `quantity` `quantity` decimal DEFAULT NULL

This is the migration I run, the postgres migration would only run after I converted empty strings to zero, it doesn't run with or without that on MySQL

```
class ChangeQuantityColumnOnItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   if connection.adapter_name.downcase == 'postgresql'
    Item.where(quantity: '').update_all(quantity: 0)
     connection.execute(%q{
       alter table items
       alter column quantity
       type decimal using quantity::decimal
     })
   else
      Item.where(quantity: '').update_all(quantity: 0)
     change_column :items, :quantity, :decimal
   end
  end

  def down
   change_column :items, :quantity, :text
  end
end
```

Comment: Try assigning string "0" to null or empty values like this: `Item.where("quantity is null or quantity=''").update_all(quantity: '0')`

Comment: I just kept it as text and used html5 validations and a number field